# Grab specific node from array that's buried within others

Tags: php

I'm getting data from an API using the following:

```
function get_web_page($url) {
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Space-X", // name of client
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
    );

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $content  = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}

    $response = get_web_page("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/latest?pretty=true");
    $resArr = array();
    $resArr = json_decode($response);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo "</pre>";
```

With the returned data I'm trying to get specific elements from the array. For example the flight number is easy enough by using:

```
$flight_number = $resArr->flight_number;
echo $flight_number;
```

But doing something like the following to get the serial number doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

```
$core_serial = $resArr->rocket->first_stage->cores->0->core_serial;
echo $core_serial;
```

Here's the output of the API:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [flight_number] => 78
    [mission_name] => CRS-17
    [mission_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => EE86F74
        )

    [launch_year] => 2019
    [launch_date_unix] => 1556952480
    [launch_date_utc] => 2019-05-04T06:48:00.000Z
    [launch_date_local] => 2019-05-04T02:48:00-04:00
    [is_tentative] => 
    [tentative_max_precision] => hour
    [tbd] => 
    [launch_window] => 0
    [rocket] => stdClass Object
        (
            [rocket_id] => falcon9
            [rocket_name] => Falcon 9
            [rocket_type] => FT
            [first_stage] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [cores] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [core_serial] => B1056
                                    [flight] => 0
                                    [block] => 5
                                    [gridfins] => 1
                                    [legs] => 1
                                    [reused] => 
                                    [land_success] => 1
                                    [landing_intent] => 1
                                    [landing_type] => ASDS
                                    [landing_vehicle] => OCISLY
                                )

                        )

                )

            [second_stage] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [block] => 5
                    [payloads] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [payload_id] => CRS-17
                                    [norad_id] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 44222
                                        )

                                    [cap_serial] => C113
                                    [reused] => 1
                                    [customers] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => NASA (CRS)
                                        )

                                    [nationality] => United States
                                    [manufacturer] => SpaceX
                                    [payload_type] => Dragon 1.1
                                    [payload_mass_kg] => 2482
                                    [payload_mass_lbs] => 5472
                                    [orbit] => ISS
                                    [orbit_params] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [reference_system] => geocentric
                                            [regime] => low-earth
                                            [longitude] => 
                                            [semi_major_axis_km] => 6787.07
                                            [eccentricity] => 0.0001369
                                            [periapsis_km] => 408.006
                                            [apoapsis_km] => 409.865
                                            [inclination_deg] => 51.6417
                                            [period_min] => 92.743
                                            [lifespan_years] => 
                                            [epoch] => 2019-05-14T13:40:22.000Z
                                            [mean_motion] => 15.5267006
                                            [raan] => 168.2377
                                            [arg_of_pericenter] => 352.6849
                                            [mean_anomaly] => 127.392
                                        )

                                    [mass_returned_kg] => 
                                    [mass_returned_lbs] => 
                                    [flight_time_sec] => 
                                    [cargo_manifest] => https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/spacex_crs-17_mission_overview.pdf
                                )

                        )

                )

            [fairings] => 
        )

    [ships] => Array
        (
            [0] => OCISLY
            [1] => Hollywood
            [2] => GOQUEST
        )

    [telemetry] => stdClass Object
        (
            [flight_club] => https://www.flightclub.io/result/2d?code=CR17
        )

    [launch_site] => stdClass Object
        (
            [site_id] => ccafs_slc_40
            [site_name] => CCAFS SLC 40
            [site_name_long] => Cape Canaveral Air Force Station Space Launch Complex 40
        )

    [launch_success] => 1
    [links] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mission_patch] => https://images2.imgbox.com/12/47/6uim8L1a_o.png
            [mission_patch_small] => https://images2.imgbox.com/fc/58/9UErD3ut_o.png
            [reddit_campaign] => https://new.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/bd2l28/crs17_launch_campaign_thread/
            [reddit_launch] => https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/bjsn0v/rspacex_crs17_official_launch_discussion_updates
            [reddit_recovery] => https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/bjy7p5/rspacex_crs17_recovery_discussion_updates_thread
            [reddit_media] => https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/bkc4d5/rspacex_crs17_media_thread_videos_images_gifs
            [presskit] => https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/crs-17_press_kit.pdf
            [article_link] => https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/05/04/spacex-launches-space-station-resupply-mission-lands-rocket-on-drone-ship/
            [wikipedia] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_CRS-17
            [video_link] => https://youtu.be/AQFhX5TvP0M
            [youtube_id] => AQFhX5TvP0M
            [flickr_images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/46856594435_206c773b5a_o.jpg
                    [1] => https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/47720639872_284e49381d_o.jpg
                    [2] => https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/46856594755_88f1b22e50_o.jpg
                    [3] => https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/47720639542_1b7c1a71b0_o.jpg
                    [4] => https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/47720639732_e04b2a9ed7_o.jpg
                    [5] => https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/32829382467_087d024428_o.jpg
                )

        )

    [details] => SpaceX's 17th Commercial Resupply Services mission for NASA out of a total of 20 contracted flights, this mission brings essential supplies to the International Space Station using SpaceX's reusable Dragon 1 spacecraft. The external payloads for this mission include Orbital Carbon Observatory 3 and Space Test Program-Houston 6. The Falcon 9 launches from SLC-40 at Cape Canaveral AFS. The booster was expected to land at LZ-1, however, due to the ongoing investigation and clean-up following the Crew Dragon testing incident, it is likely to land on OCISLY instead.

    [upcoming] => 
    [static_fire_date_utc] => 2019-04-27T07:23:00.000Z
    [static_fire_date_unix] => 1556349780
    [timeline] => stdClass Object
        (
            [webcast_liftoff] => 900
            [go_for_prop_loading] => -2280
            [rp1_loading] => -2100
            [stage1_lox_loading] => -2100
            [stage2_lox_loading] => -960
            [engine_chill] => -420
            [prelaunch_checks] => -60
            [propellant_pressurization] => -60
            [go_for_launch] => -45
            [ignition] => -3
            [liftoff] => 0
            [maxq] => 72
            [meco] => 137
            [stage_sep] => 141
            [second_stage_ignition] => 148
            [first_stage_boostback_burn] => 154
            [first_stage_entry_burn] => 399
            [first_stage_landing] => 507
            [seco-1] => 519
            [dragon_separation] => 578
            [dragon_solar_deploy] => 728
            [dragon_bay_door_deploy] => 8340
        )

)
```

Comment: Array access is done via `[index]` or `[key]`, not via `->` …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array down there in the mix, specifically  `cores`

See how it is annotated on the dump `[cores] => Array` rather than, for example `[rocket] => stdClass Object`

so

```
$core_serial = $resArr->rocket->first_stage->cores[0]->core_serial;
```